# You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Was wondering if someone could find the error in this:

```
    $sqlinsert = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
\'$target_path\' INTO TABLE 'db_usergroup' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'";
```

`$target_path` varies slightly in its exact name, but an example would be:

```
temp/24_09_12_16_57_27_invoice_example.csv
```

I get this error:

```
    An error occurred. The file could not be imported. 
Error with MySQL Query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'\'temp/24_09_12_16_57_27_invoice_example.csv' INTO TABLE 
'db_usergroup' FIELDS T' at line 1
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make life easier, and less error-prone, by using heredoc syntax.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

Why are you escaping the quotes in your target path? I don't believe that's necessary.

You can usually tell exactly what the error is by examining the first few characters after `for the right syntax to use near`, and this does seem to indicate the backslash is at fault.

Try:

```
$sqlinsert = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$target_path' INTO TABLE ...
```

Comment: also, what's the convention for enclosing table names ? :)

Comment: Erik: yes, but I suspect that would be the _next_ problem :-) This particular one is caused by the escaping. I won't add that to my answer since MarcB has already covered it.

Comment: @Erik I have tried not escaping the target path but it also gives an error, do as both you and Marc have suggested and various combinations of both, I still get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

`'db_usergroup'` is invalid. The `'` single quotes turn that tablename into a string, which MySQL will barf on. You do not need to quote/escape table or field names unless they are reserved words. And for that, you use backticks, e.g.

```
LOAD DATA ... `db_usergroup` ...
              ^--          ^--
```

---

followup:

```
$sqlinsert = <<<EOL
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$target_path'
INTO TABLE db_usergroup
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
EOL;
```

Comment: Having done it so that it is:
$sqlinsert = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'$target_path\' INTO TABLE `db_usergroup` FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' ENCLOSED BY \'\"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\r\\n\'";
I now get:
An error occured. The file could not be imported. Error with MySQL Query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\',\' ENCLOSED BY \'"\' ESCAPED BY \'\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'' at line 1

Comment: You're over-escaping. There's no need to escape `'` quotes in a `"`-quoted string. MySQl will see those escape chars and think you're trying to use a literal `'` as part of fieldnames and whatnot.

Comment: Ok I've tried a few combinations, and just can't seem to quite get it, im obviously missing the obvious. Are you able to spell it out for me? Thanks.

Comment: @SeánMcCabe: see edit. Note that I switched to using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc), which is my preferred method for doing multi-line string assignments. Doing this particular string build with a normal `"` quoted string would be identical, howerver.

Comment: Attempted what you gave me but I get the following:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/html/energynet/management/classes/uploader.php on line 45
Line 45 being $sqlinsert = <<<EOL
Attempted to do it with " aswell and get similar issues as before